# generating table rows for objects with children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, jsx

Im trying to display a bunch of objects in table format. If the object has a child, i'd like it displayed in the next row before continuing down the array to the next object.

In my example below I successfully render a table showing all top level or parent objects:

```
const renderCategories = (categories) => {
            let myCategories = [];
            for(let category of categories){
                myCategories.push(
                    <tr key={category.name}>
                        <td><input type="checkbox"></input></td>
                        <td>{category.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                );
            }

            return myCategories;
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="checkbox"></input></th>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {renderCategories(category.categories)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
};
```

In my original version i wasn't using a table but instead using lists and so achieved what i was looking for by doing something like:

```
const renderCategories = (categories) => {
                let myCategories = [];
                for(let category of categories){
                    myCategories.push(
                        <li key={category.name}>
                          {category.name}
                          {category.children.length > 0 ? 
                            {<ul>renderCategories(category.children)}</ul>) : null}
                        </li>
    
                    );
                }
    
                return myCategories;
        }
```

This solution obviously wont work for my new use case as I cant render table rows inside table rows.  This is driving me crazy as no alternative seems to work.  I could achieve my desired design using divs instead of a table. However I want to use a table, or at least know how to do it by using a table.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.flatMap()` and array spread to return a flattened array of `<tr>` elements.

Note: I've also added the indentation using `level` and empty `<td>` elements. You remove the `Array.from()` line, and the `level` if not needed.

```js
const renderCategories = (categories, level = 0) => 
  categories.flatMap(({ name, children }) => {
    const cat = (
      <tr key={name}>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></input></td>
        {Array.from({ length: level }, (_, i) => <td key={i}></td>)}
        <td>{name}</td>
      </tr>
    );
    
    return children.length ?
      [cat, ...renderCategories(children, level + 1)]
      :
      cat;
  });
  
const Demo = ({ categories }) => (
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox"></input></th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {renderCategories(categories)}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);

const categories = [{ name: 'A', children: [{ name: 'A1', children: [] }, { name: 'A2', children: [] }] }, { name: 'B', children: [{ name: 'B1', children: [{ name: 'B1-1', children: [] }, { name: 'B1-2', children: [] }] }, { name: 'B2', children: [] }] }]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo categories={categories} />,
  root
)
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```